# vim key mapping for command string starting e.g. 9:s/pat/sub/ge<cr>:

Tags: vim, mapping

If I want to run a :s command on 9 lines of text I type 9:s and vim sets up the command line as

```
:.,+8s
```

which is very useful. But how can I get that behavior to apply in a key mapping?

I've tried the following starts to the mapping:

```
nmap _p :s/etc  
nmap _p :^Us/etc  
nmap _p ^U:s/etc  
nmap _p :^Ulet @l=v:count1<cr>:exe @l.'s/etc'  
nmap _p :^Ulet @l=v:count1<cr>:exe @l.':s/etc'  
nmap _p :^Ulet @l=v:count1<cr>:exe '.,+'.@l-1.'s/etc'
```

The first 3 all treated 9_p as if it were _p, the next 2 treated it as _p but applied it to line 10 of the text, while the last effort behaved like the first 3

Comment: I am not sure I understand which mapping you are trying to create. Do you want a mapping which execute a substitution on the 8 lines under your cursor (plus the line where your cursor is)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:normal` to take the count for the mapping:

```
nmap _p :normal :s/etc/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following map:

```
nnoremap _p :<c-u>exe".,+".v:count." s/etc"<cr>
```

which will execute the command `.,+N s/etc` where `N` is the normal mode count.